# use recursion to find the greatest common divisor in C

Tags: c, recursion, greatest-common-divisor

here is my code, when the input is **21,15** I got the output is **0**. what I expected is **3**. the return value of the function **divisor** seems return a wrong value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int divisor(int a, int b){
    //when b is 0, got the GCD
    if(b==0){
        printf("when b is 0, a=%d\n", a);  
        return a;
    }
    else{
        //recursion
        printf("the input a=%d,b=%d\n", b, a%b);
        divisor(b, a%b);
    }
    // return res;
}

int main(void){
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d,%d", &a, &b);
    int r = divisor(a, b);
    printf("%d", r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should return the result of the recursive call, otherwise undefined behaviour...

Comment: Offtopic: *'divisor'* might be just *any*, but you want the greatest common one – so I recommend naming the function appropriately...

Comment: @Aconcagua thx for your help! So I should use the `return divisor(b, a%b)` instead of `divisor(b, a%b)`, I will change its name to gmd :)

Comment: @pipi yes, obviously. `divisor(b, a%b);` calls the function and throws away the return value.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this, but it will only work for positive integers.

```
int divisor(int a, int b){
    if (a * b == 0){
        return a+b;
    }

    return divisor(b % a, a % b);
}
```